# Basic questions about using .NET to call a generic non-.NET web service

Tags: .net

I've had some experience calling .NET asmx and svc services but for the most part have relied on Visual Studio's Add Web Reference Wizard to generate that proxy that I sued to call the web service.  I realize that using this wizard may not be the ideal way to go, but that is a probably another separate topic, my question is even more basic:

I was provided a WSDL and a bunch of xsd files. I then browsed the WSDL looking for a URL that appeared to be internal to our company and copied and pasted it into the "Add Service Reference" dialog box.

```
https://a-entesb.sys.MyCompany.com:64005/MemberServicesGatewayG7Web/sca/ComeFolder
```

When I pushed the "go" button I got this error:

```
The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://a-entesb.sys.MyCompany.com:64005/MemberServicesGatewayG7Web/sca/SomeFolder'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://a-entesb.sys.MyCompany.com:64005/MemberServicesGatewayG7Web/sca/SomeFolder'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

When I use a browser to navigate to the URL, I first get a warning that the security certificate has expired. When I click 'OK to continue' I get a HTML message:

```
<h1>Hello! This is an Axis2 Web Service! <h1>
```

Note that the web wervice url that I am using did not include a file suffix such as .asmx or svc but then again, this web service was probably not developed using Microsoft tools. However, I know that web services are supposed to be generic and I am wondering if the "Add Service Reference" wizard should be able to detect any web serviceand genererate a proxy object for me  provided that the url was correct.

I don't think I am going to get much if any help from the technical peopel that are hosting this service. I don't think they even wrote it.

Will an expired certificate interfere with my ability to call the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the URL that leads to the WSDL file, or else save the file and associated XSD files to a disk location, then pass the path to that location to "Add Service Reference".

Comment: I tried to point to the wsdl on my local PC, but I think it tired to follow a chain of referenced xsd files and eventually hit some that I was not provided.

Comment: Get them all and this will work. Alternatively, ask for the URL for the WSDL.

Comment: They are telling me they already sent it to me. My preference would be to point to an online deployed WSDL rather than files that were sent as an attachment, I feel that I am more likely to get correct/complete info without having to come back repeatedly and say "I am still missing a file." But I wonder: Is the WSDL necessarily part of the web service deployment? I don't see if in my .NET web services.

Comment: WSDL/XSD files are often generated from the classes in the service. That's true both for WCF and ASMX services.